# What kind of karma causes someone to be born with same-sex attractions and the emotional/mental pain that comes with it?

Tags: karma, afterlife, homosexuality

The emotional and mental pain of being a homosexual is because the world is at odds with who you're . You're a misfit and a minority in this world.
Straight (" normal" ) peers mock you which breaks your heart.
You fall in love with one straight guy because most guys are not gay. which again causes heartbreak
One day your parents (Indian) marry you off to a woman which causes you guilt too. And you live a suffocating life, all the while being deprived of meaningful emotional intimacy with another man.
You feel your entire existence is a curse. A life sentence you have no option but to bear :(

I can't imagine this being anything except some manifestation of bad karma of a past life
I don't know what I did in one of my past lives to be born as a gay man and not a straight man.

But I guess its something like outraging the modesty of a woman, or being a cause of breaking up love partners
I really don't know

but I am curious to know, what do scriptures say

Comment: There is nothing wrong with being gay or bi or trans or non-binary or anything else. Every orientation or gender is all good. So please don't believe that. I think there is huge misinterpretations with scripture. Things have got messed up and interpreted all wrong, with so much stuff ! So don't even worry about it. What matters is how you treat people, how you act. Are you honest, honorable, kind, gentle with people and animals and the earth. Are you trying to sincerely learn and be best good person you can be. Are you trying to never hurt anyone. That is only stuff that matters.

Comment: You are perfecr just how you are. I guarantee it. Just only concentrate to be a good person, do good stuffs, learn as much as you can. Anyone tells you different is not correctly understanding things in my opinion. Huge hugs friend ! No worries